# Android project creation error

Tags: android, android-studio

When i click on next button of android project creation it just hanged

[image]

Comment: Just tick phone and tablets option in your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select an option from the screen to create a project depending on which device you want to create an app for. If you want to create it for `phone or tablet` click on `Phone and Tablet` option and then click `next`. It will work.

You can also select the `minimum android version` that your app will support for the device on which your app will run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the checkbox depend on for which device you want to develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my device, the RAM was not enough that is why the device was hanged.